# Density of wooden materials

Tags: everyday-chemistry, density

Would all wooden materials have the same density? Why or why not? (Examples may help). I have the following solution to the question: No, not all wooden materials would have the same density. Due to the makeup and properties of the components found inside certain wooden materials.

Comment: You might want to migrate this to [the DIY/Home Improvement SE site](http://diy.stackexchange.com/), where some folks with hands-on experience can address your question.

Answer (score 1):

You might find this table of *[Wood Densities](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/wood-density-d_40.html)* helpful. For example, note the density of balsa and that of Lignum Vitae. In fact, Lignum Vitae is *so* dense that [it has been used for bearings](http://lignum-vitae-bearings.com/about-lignum/) on ships and even nuclear sub!

Answer (score 0):

No, the sieve tubes(things that carry water and food around the plant) are different sizes depending on type of plant. Check out this video, it shows the difference in the the size of the tubes. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6t2AZubF8U